# Reading states of multiple toggle switches

Tags: serial

I'm working on modifying this [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Switch) from the Arduino website to read the state of 3 toggle (SPDT) switches. If I have one toggle switch hooked up, my sketch works as expected...the sketch will log the state of the switch in the serial debugger every-time the state changes, and only when the state changes.

However, if I add in two more switches, the serial debugger will continuously output my log messages, without detecting if the state has changed.

Here's the code from my sketch:

```
const int  switchOnePin = 2;    // digital in 2 (pin the switch one is attached to)
const int  switchTwoPin = 3;    // digital in 3 (pin the switch two is attached to)
const int  switchThreePin = 4;  // digital in 4 (pin the switch three is attached to)

int switchOneState = 0;         // current state of the switch
int lastSwitchOneState = 0;     // previous state of the switch

int switchTwoState = 0;         
int lastSwitchTwoState = 0;     

int switchThreeState = 0;         
int lastSwitchThreeState = 0;     


void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  int switchOneState = 0;         // current state of the switch
  int lastSwitchOneState = 0;     // previous state of the switch switch pins as an input
  pinMode(switchOnePin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switchTwoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switchThreePin, INPUT);
}


void loop() {

  // read the switch input pins:
  switchOneState   = digitalRead(switchOnePin);
  delay(50);
  switchTwoState   = digitalRead(switchTwoPin);
  delay(50);
  switchThreeState = digitalRead(switchThreePin);

  // compare the switchState to its previous state
  if (switchOneState != lastSwitchOneState) {
  // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (switchOneState == HIGH) {
    // if the current state is HIGH then the button
    // went from off to on:
    Serial.println("Switch one is on");
  }
  else {
    // if the current state is LOW then the button
    // went from on to off:
    Serial.println("Switch one is off");
  }




  if (switchTwoState != lastSwitchTwoState) {
    if (switchTwoState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Switch two is on");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Switch two is off");
  }

  if (switchThreeState != lastSwitchThreeState) {
    if (switchThreeState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Switch three is on");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Switch thre is off");
  }
 }
}
  // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
  delay(50);  
}
// save the current state as the last state,
//for next time through the loop
lastSwitchOneState   = switchOnePin;
lastSwitchTwoState   = switchTwoPin;
lastSwitchThreeState = switchThreePin;
}
```

And here's what my circuit looks like:

[image]
Does anyone have any insight into what I may be doing wrong? I'm not quite sure if it's a circuit or a sketch issue (or both).

**EDIT** I tried adding a delay of 50ms between each digital input read, but that still did not seem to help the problem.

Comment: Not sure this is the entirety of the problem, or if it's just a "transcription" error when you made your circuit diagram, but you've got both sides of your switches connected to +5V. One side should be connected to ground, and the other to +5V.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen, yes, that is just a transcription error...thank you for catching that!

Comment: A bit off topic: why aren't you using the internal pullup resistors? You could simply connect the input to GND (for logical zero) or leave them open (for logical one, courtesy of the pullup resistor).

Comment: @IgorStoppa, I just wasn't aware they could work that way to be honest (still a beginner with Arduino)

Comment: I think your `{}` bracketing got a bit messed up, do you intend to only check the state of switch two if switch one changed?

Comment: Sort out the formatting of your program and you should immediately see your error.  This is a good example where proper indenting is vitally important.  Don't get lazy right from the beginning and force yourself to lay your programs out properly. It'll become a good habit to get into.

Comment: @BrettAM, that seems like it could be right...I had wanted to check the states of all the switches while the sketch is running.

Comment: @BrettAM That said, I'm not quite seeing where my bracketing has broken down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was two pronged---both the copy/paste error that @Gerben pointed out, as well as the incorrect if-else statements that @BrettAM pointed out. Below is the working code:

```
const int  switchOnePin = 2;    // digital in 2 (pin the switch one is attached to)
const int  switchTwoPin = 3;    // digital in 3 (pin the switch two is attached to)
const int  switchThreePin = 4;  // digital in 4 (pin the switch three is attached to)

int switchOneState = 0;         // current state of the switch
int lastSwitchOneState = 0;     // previous state of the switch

int switchTwoState = 0;
int lastSwitchTwoState = 0;

int switchThreeState = 0;
int lastSwitchThreeState = 0;


void setup() {
    //initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
    Serial.begin(9600);

    int switchOneState = 0;         // current state of the switch
    int lastSwitchOneState = 0;     // previous state of the switch switch pins as an input
    pinMode(switchOnePin, INPUT);
    pinMode(switchTwoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(switchThreePin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // read the switch input pins:
    switchOneState   = digitalRead(switchOnePin);
    switchTwoState   = digitalRead(switchTwoPin);
    switchThreeState = digitalRead(switchThreePin);

    // compare the switchState to its previous state
    if (switchOneState != lastSwitchOneState) {
        // if the state has changed, increment the counter
        if (switchOneState == HIGH) {
        // if the current state is HIGH then the button
        // went from off to on:
            Serial.println("Switch one is on");
        } else {
            // if the current state is LOW then the button
            // went from on to off:
            Serial.println("Switch one is off");
        }
    }

    if (switchTwoState != lastSwitchTwoState) {
        if (switchTwoState == HIGH) {
            Serial.println("Switch two is on");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Switch two is off");
        }
    }

    if (switchThreeState != lastSwitchThreeState) {
        if (switchThreeState == HIGH) {
            Serial.println("Switch three is on");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Switch thre is off");
        }
    }

    // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);

    // save the current state as the last state,
    //for next time through the loop
    lastSwitchOneState   = switchOneState;
    lastSwitchTwoState   = switchTwoState;
    lastSwitchThreeState = switchThreeState;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lastSwitchOneState   = switchOnePin;
lastSwitchTwoState   = switchTwoPin;
lastSwitchThreeState = switchThreePin;
```

should be

```
lastSwitchOneState   = switchOneState;
lastSwitchTwoState   = switchTwoState;
lastSwitchThreeState = switchThreeState;
```

Comment: That's definitely part of the problem; so I did mark it up. Thank you! Still only able to read the result of switch one though.